# Finding the sum of many square root values (greatest integer function)?

Tags: sequences-and-series, ceiling-and-floor-functions

[image: Problem]

I am not really sure how to go about this mathematically, but I used my programming skills to find the answer quite quickly:

```
public static void main(String[]args) 
{ 
int x; 
int p = 0; 

for(x = 0; x <= 36; x++) 
{ 
p+=Math.sqrt(x);    
} 
System.out.println(p); 
}
```

What this does is adds each square root value to the past value all the way to sqr(36). The sum ends up being 131 or B. I can't really get anywhere outside of this, so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: You need to pay attention to the values $N$ such that $\sqrt{N}$ is an integer, namely $1,4,9,16,25$ and $36$. Now, for instance, if $4 \leq N < 9$, then $2 \leq \sqrt{N} < 3$, so that $\lfloor{\sqrt{N}}\rfloor = 2$. So, for instance, $\lfloor{\sqrt{4}}\rfloor + \lfloor{\sqrt{5}}\rfloor + \lfloor{\sqrt{6}}\rfloor + \lfloor{\sqrt{7}}\rfloor + \lfloor{\sqrt{8}}\rfloor = 2 + 2 + 2 + 2 + 2 = 5 \cdot 2 = 10$.

Can you finish it from here?

Comment: So sqr(9)+sqr(10)+sqr(11) = 5 • 2 = 10 as well?

Comment: No. Do you understand what the "greatest integer function" or "floor function" means?

Comment: Doesn't it mean to round down?

Comment: So your saying that numbers within 4≤N< 9 since sqr(4) = 2 and your rounding down. So 9≤N<16 = 3? And 16≤N<25 = 4? etc...?

Comment: That's right. Now just add everything up and you get the answer. You can do this rather fast if you notice that there are $2n+1$ integers between $n^2$ (inclusive) and $(n+1)^2$ (exclusive).